# How to give space dynamically between tabBar items in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar

I have a tab bar with 4 tab items but I have to add space between tab items on run time.

[image: image having 4 tabitems]

when the user clicks on any of the second, third, and fourth items the plus button gets added in the middle of the item but it looks very close to the items

[image: Image having add button in the middle]

so I need little space between respective items on run time.

I am adding that button to the `UITabBarController` class

```
   import UIKit

class TabBarVC: UITabBarController {
    
    @IBOutlet var tabBarView: UITabBar!
    @IBOutlet var floatButtonView: UIView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showAddButton(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showAddButton"), object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.hideAddButton(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "hideAddButton"), object: nil)
        
        
        self.floatButtonView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 65.0, height: 65.0)
        let xPosition = (self.view.frame.width / 2) - 32
        let yPosition = (self.view.frame.height - ((self.tabBarView.frame.height * 2) + 15))
        let width = floatButtonView.frame.size.width
        let height = floatButtonView.frame.size.height
        self.floatButtonView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: width, height: height)
        self.view.addSubview(self.floatButtonView)
        self.floatButtonView.isHidden = true
        tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 10
        tabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        
        tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -6, bottom: 0, right: 6)
        
   
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        self.tabBar.itemPositioning = .centered
        self.tabBar.itemSpacing = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 5
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
    
    @objc func showAddButton(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        self.floatButtonView.isHidden = false
    }
    
    @objc func hideAddButton(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        self.floatButtonView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

I need to add the space between tab bars in the middle at run time.

Comment: Try appropriate values for the `imageInsets` of the `UITabBarItem`.

Comment: so what you want is always you will have 4 tabs. But at some scenarios you want total 5 tabs. Correct?

Comment: Not 5 tabs I want, I just want when a user is on 1st tab will show 4 tabs on the tab bar but when the user switches to the tab the plus button appears in the middle with the appropriate space.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.tabBar.itemPositioning = .centered
    self.tabBar.itemSpacing = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 5
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but nothing is working. I am updating the code on top. @HangarRash

Comment: change the divider 5 to other 2 3 4 5 6 7 you will get how it works

Comment: self.tabBar.itemPositioning = .centered,
 self.tabBar.itemSpacing = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2,
 self.tabBar.isTranslucent = false, this is how I implement